how to convert my string to object to use in map
I have a map script.  I have a string for one of the properties to use in displaying the map.
The 'Position' is {lat:lat value, lng: longitude value }.
I created a string that looks correct. The variable is showing up as the variable name 'position'.
I tried to use parse.JSON to convert it, but it still only shows up as the variable name. What am I tried this:  var position = JSON.parse('{"lat:" + latitude + ",lng:" + longitude }');
But, the word, 'position' shows up instead of the value.  Why doesn't this work?
Thanks for your help

What you've posted is a syntax error, please give a [mre] (and always include a language in the tags).

You're trying to use string concatenation within the JSON.parse method which isn't correctly formatting the string as valid JSON before parsing it. The correct way to dynamically create your JSON string involves proper concatenation of your variables with the string, ensuring the whole string is valid JSON. Then, JSON.parse() can be used to convert this string into an object.
However, in your case you don't need to go through the JSON conversion process because the values for latitude and longitude are already available. You can directly assign the latitude and longitude values to an object like this:
var position = {lat: parseFloat(latitude), lng: parseFloat(longitude)};

Make sure that latitude and longitude are either strings that can be parsed into floats or are already numbers. The parseFloat() function is used here to ensure that the latitude and longitude values are treated as floating-point numbers, which is the correct format for latitudes and longitudes.
This approach is more efficient and straightforward than creating a JSON string and parsing it, especially since you're already working within JavaScript and don't need to serialize/deserialize the data.
